# Socket mobile scanner with web application on iPad trigger buttonclick event

Tags: asp.net, ipad, barcode-scanner, socketmobile

I have built an ASP.NET web forms application (webpage) based warehouse manager where I am investigating how to use a Socket mobile scanner together with an Ipad (or other tablet) to scan stockplace numbers and article numbers. At the moment I am trying to scan a stockplace number into a textbox in a listview control (in edititemtemplate) and that works. Unfortunately the scanner seems to trigger a buttonclick event outside the listview and that in turn take me to an error page. I have no clue why this happens. If I return to the first page the stockplace is scanned ok in the textbox. This happens both in Safari and Chrome browsers. Is there anyone who has experience of this and know how to handle it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are being taken to an error page, because the scanner appends a carriage return to the end of the data by default. Since you are scanning into a web form, the carriage return submits the form which is incomplete.

You can remove the carriage return using the following command barcode

**Data As-Is** - Configures the CHS to return only the decoded data (i.e. no prefix or suffix).
*Applies to the 7Ci, 7Di, 8Ci, 7Qi and 7Xi in HID mode*

[image: Data as-is, no prefix or suffix, command barcode for imagers]

Since you are scanning into a web form, you may want the cursor to advance to the next field so the user can continue to input data. In that case, you can configure the scanner to append a tab instead

**Tab** - Configures the CHS to add a tab after decoded data.
*Applies to the 7Ci, 7Di, 8Ci, 7Qi and 7Xi in HID mode*

[image: Tab suffix command barcode for imagers]

If you are not able to scan the barcodes off the screen, you may have a laser scanner which has different command barcodes. I didn't include those, because you can't scan them off the screen anyway-you need to print them out.

All the [command barcode sheets](http://www.socketmobile.com/support/Downloads/CHS-Downloads/series-7-manuals-documentation) are available on the Socket Mobile website.

*Disclosure: I am a consultant to Socket Mobile, Inc.*

Comment: Hi Enrico! Thank you for your interesting answer. I found another solution to this problem though. Since I am working in an asp.net web forms listview control, where I am scanning to a textbox on every row and a buttonclick event outside the listview somehow gets fired while I I added the following code in my button_click function to prevent it to do anything, in this case go to the custom error page. The listview shall be in itemmode to be able to do the button-click event.

if (lvwMyListview.EditItem == null)
{
    //Do the button-click event
}